# How to return file content using asynchronous callback response?

Tags: javascript, file, asynchronous

I have this code

```
 function gotFile(file){
    readAsText(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {  
      var string = evt.target.result;       
    };
      alert(string) // returns null 
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Apparently I'm trying to get result from asynchronous callback in synchronous function and that's not possible.

So I've changed my code like this :

```
function gotFile(file){
    readAsText(file,function(str){
        return str;
        });
}

function readAsText(file,callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
     callback(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
    alert(callback);
}
```

returns me the string

```
function(str){
        return str;
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your updated version you are still trying to use an asynchronous operation as if it were synchronous.

In the `callback` function, returning the `str` value is pointless. You need to *do* something with the `str` value instead, right there inside `callback` (or in another function that you *call* from `callback`).

For example:

```
function gotFile(file){
    readAsText(file,function(str){
        alert(str);
    });
}

function readAsText(file,callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
     callback(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Note the difference: Instead of returning `str` from `callback`, we do something with `str` (call the `alert` function) right there.

Comment: I want to put this string value in a global variable and use it in an other function. Doing an alert of it doesn't help me

Comment: How will your other function know that the string value is ready? It won't. You need to call that other function from your callback.

Comment: Really ? I can't wait for it in this function and use it after in an other ?

Comment: The problem that you're wrestling with here is the timing of when these functions get called. It's understandable that you'd want to put the value in a global to use later, but that's not how things work. You have to have some way to let that other function know that the data is ready, and you do that by calling it at the time it's ready. That is inside the callback function.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it's helpful. This issue trips up just about everyone when they start working with asynchronous JavaScript code, so you're not alone! :-) Give a shout with any further related questions...